# Undefined index: user_image - What am I missing?

Tags: php, mysqli

Trying to create a photo uploader however I keep receiving these errors for 'user_image', what am I missing? Any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

Error is: Undefined index: user_image

PHP code:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $image_path = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, 'img/'.$_FILES['user_image']['name']);


        //Make sure file is an image
        if (preg_match("!image!", $_FILES['user_image']['type'])) {
            //copy image to images folder
            if (copy($_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'], $image_path)) {
                $_SESSION['user_image'] = $image_path;

                $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_image)";
                    "VALUES('$image_path')";

                //If the query is successful
                if ($sql == true) {
                    $_SESSION['message'] = "Profile picture uploaded.";
                } else {
                    //Error handling
                    $_SESSION['message'] = "Image could not be uploaded.";
                }
            } else {
                $_SESSION['message'] = "File upload failed.";
            }
        }
    } else {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Please only uplaod JPEG, PNG or GIF files.";
    }
```

Html code:

```
<form class="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="container">
         <span class="user"><img src='<?= $_SESSION['user_image']?>'</span>
         </div>
        <div class="user_image"><input type="file" name="user_image" accept="img/*" /></div>
        <button type="submit" name="submit">UPLOAD</button>
      </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: where is your form?

    $_FILES['user_image'] does not exist

Comment: user_image is defined in my database, is that not correct? @Kapsonfire

Comment: Mixing `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']` and `$_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name']`, how did you name that field in your form?

Comment: If you mean my database (sorry - not great with the terminology haha), it is defined as user_image. Sorry 'image' isnt supposed to be in there, this was when I was messing around with it trying to fix it. Ill take it out the snippet now :) @kerbholz

Comment: Not your database, but your HTML form (`<form action="" ...>`) where you have your input elements. There should be one for your file upload

Comment: Oh sorry, its defined as user_image in my html, i have attached the html code above :) @kerbholz